# Using Jquery DataTable when assigning to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm going through an issue with Jquery DataTables.

I have several DataTables, but I want to assign only one of them to another variable and use it.

Small code for exemple below:

```
var time = "morning";
var helloTable;

var goodMorningTable = $('#goodMorning').DataTable({
...
});

var goodAfternoonTable = $('#goodAfternoon').DataTable({
...
});

var goodEveningTable = $('#goodEvening').DataTable({
...
});

function sayHello(time) {
    switch(time) {
        case "morning":
            helloTable = goodMorningTable;
            break;
        case "afternoon":
            helloTable = goodAfternoonTable;
            break;
        case "evening":
            helloTable = goodEveningTable;
            break;
    }

    helloTable.draw(); // And do more things with it 
}

$('#btnAfternoon').on('click', function () {
    sayHello("afternoon");
});
```

My code is more complicated than that but follows more or less the same structure. My DataTables data come from the server (AJAX).

In debug mode I can see that the `draw()` instruction is executed but nothing happens. I see that nothing happens because there is no "loading" time.

Please tell me if it's not clear enough.

What can you suggest to make it work?

Thanks in advance.